# ListView Problem in Android?

Tags: android, listview

how to implement the [slow adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html) example in ApiDemos for multiple line list view? i want to do this for the multiple line list view when scrollstatechanged? any idea?? tutorial, sample code are most thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Offhand it looks like you just need to switch the xml you inflate from to handle your needs and edit the getView() to populate it appropriately.

Comment: what i have to do. in Slow adapter example. just inflate the textview.